# is it possible to use variables before being assigned in php code?

Tags: php, variables, variable-assignment

for some particular reason, I need to use some variables' values before they are assigned.
I want them assigned to a variable which is followed by them. which means as for now, the value assigned is null..

is this silly question? do i have to find a better design?, but for now for some reason this approach seems to be the very shortcut to my end

```
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
    $cat_number = 'k'.$i;
    // and some code to write $value to server with index $cat_number
}

$i = 1; // can be some other number in later use
foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
    $i++; // $i can be some random number due to particular purpose
    // and some more code to show $cat
}
```

the reason i need to put $_POST foreach above is, so the content POSTed will automatically show upon submission (which is handled by the rest of code)

Comment: _"is this silly question?"_. Impossible to tell without code.

Comment: What are you doing? Why would you do that? Please be more specific.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: code updated as abridged version

Comment: Are those loops in two separate scripts? If not, is there any reason why they can't be swapped around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  What would a variable equal before you assigned a value to it?

Null, of course.  PHP would treat the variable as null, throw an error, and carry on.

Comment: I guess impossible is right

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know for sure without seeing your code, but it sounds like you need assignment by reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is set a reference to a variable so that when it gets set later your reference contains the new value as well. If so your question is worded very badly. So you might try:

```
$nullVariable = null;
$myReference =& $nullVariable;

echo $myReference; // this will echo an empty string
$nullVariable = 'Now I have a value';
echo $myReference; // now this will echo 'Now I have a value'
```